# Having problems populating child associations in FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to create a parent model with a certain number of children.

The associations are set up like this:

```
search_keyword_url has_many :competitors

competitor belongs_to :search_keyword_url
```

My FactoryGirl definitions are:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :url, :class => SearchKeywordUrl, aliases: [:search_keyword_url] do
    user
    sequence(:url) {|n| "http://example#{n}.com"}
  end

  factory :competitor do
    search_keyword_url
    sequence(:url) {|n| "http://competitor#{n}.com"}
  end
end
```

These two are working just fine when used individually. I also need a factory that would associate the parent with 5 children. I've come up with this:

```
factory :url_with_5_competitors, :parent => :search_keyword_url do |search_keyword_url|
    search_keyword_url.after_create { |sku| 5.times { create(:competitor, :search_keyword_url => sku ) } }
end
```

But when I try to create an url_with_5_competitors in my test:

```
create(:url_with_5_competitors)
```

... I receive the following error:

> Failure/Error: create(:url_with_5_competitors)
>      ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
>      SearchKeywordUrl(#35692) expected, got # < Class:0xd351f72>(#35694)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `build_list` instead?

```
factory :url_with_5_competitors, :parent => :search_keyword_url do |search_keyword_url|
    competitors { build_list :competitor, 5 }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You might prefer this syntax with traits:

```
  factory :url, :class => SearchKeywordUrl, aliases: [:search_keyword_url] do
    user
    sequence(:url) {|n| "http://example#{n}.com"}

    trait :with_5_competitors do
      competitors { build_list :competitor, 5 }
    end
  end
```

#### usage

```
create(:url, :with_5_competitors)
```